# Convert positive number to a negative number - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, numbers, integer

I have a simple app with an integer. I want to check the value in the integer and change it from a positive to a negative if it is a positive value. I also want it to check to see if the integer is a negative and then change it to a positive if it is currently a negative. The code below is what I thought of:

```
int number;

// number gets set.... etc...

// Now do number check.
if (number > 0) {
    number = (0 - number);
}

else if (number < 0) {

    // Since number is negative, lets try to
    // minus minus the number and make it positive.
    number = (0 - number);
}
```

My question is, is my method correct and more importantly a good way of achieving this functionality? I read that you can use a method called `abs()` but from what I understand its not safe?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Unless you're doing thousands of conversions, there's not much point in trying to optimize it. (0 - number) could be replaced with just -number though.

Comment: Ummm... `number = -number;` or `number *= -1;` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have look at your code and let's boil it down:

```
 // Now do number check.
if (number > 0) 
{
  number = (0 - number);
}
else if (number < 0) 
{
  // Since number is negative, lets try to
  // minus minus the number and make it positive.
  number = (0 - number);
}
```

Obviously the statements inside both `if`-branches are identically. So you can write:

```
// Now do number check.
if (number > 0 || number < 0)  // || means logical or
{
  number = (0 - number);
}
```

If you take into account that -0 is 0, you can remove the whole `if`:

```
number = (0 - number);
```

Additionally you can write, …

```
number = -number
```

… too or use a multiplication as intended by the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
int number;

number *= -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working as well:

```
-(number)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write int myNum *= -1; It will change your num to negative.